# When we have XML-APIS dependency in class path, spring boot application is not coming up in websphere 8.5. class loader is PARENT_LAST

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-ee-6, websphere-8, xmlapi2

In spring boot application we are dependent on Sax XML parsers and dozer mappers. So we have used xercesImpl.jar which internally has xml-apis as dependency.
When we install and run application in WAS, giving exception as below,

*java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFctory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)*

When I excluded xml-apis dependency then app is coming up but it's failing to load dozer xmls, with below exception

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal*

We have set application class loader config to parent last as spring boot 2.3.12 is conflicting with parent first class loder config.

**Versions**
Spring boot - 2.3.12,
xercesImpl.jar - 2.12.2,
xml-apis - 1.4,
Websphere - 8.5,
Class Loader : PARENT_LAST

**Summarising - with xml-apis, app is not coming up. If we exclude xml-apis app is coming up but nothing working.**

Looking for suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Try to create separate, isolated shared libraries with all the xml, dozer jars and attach it to the server classloader, and run app with parent last option.

Comment: I was tried to find out which classes in xml-apis were
 really being used  which were not provided in JDK to load XML. Got to know ElementTraversal is the only interface which is missed and rest all were part of JDK. so created that interface alone with same package. that resolved my issue.